# Search Params Issue on the Next.js Static Site (S3)

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, next.js13, static-site-generation, urlsearchparams

I have two headers in my Next js Static site (S3) project. When I'm toggle headers based on search params getting default header first and then route to actual header.

I know it's due to availability of search parameters on the client side. But how to tackle this issue of getting default Header first and then on the client side I'm routed to actual header.

I want default header only visible when search params is not available but when time of availability of search params it has route to actual header instead of getting into default header and then to actual header.

I need to get the default header when there is no search params, if I have search params i need to route to actual header based on search parameters with out getting into default header of Next.js static site (S3).

**Or**

I need how get searchParams on Next js Static site hosting (S3)
on the the server side and not on the client side